# How can I add Bootstrap 4 to the library django-summernote?

Tags: python, django, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, summernote

I need to add Bootstrap 4 to [django-summernote](https://github.com/summernote/django-summernote). Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [Django-summernote](https://github.com/summernote/django-summernote) is served with Bootstrap3 by default, but you can
>   choose another options. You can change the theme by SUMMERNOTE_THEME =
>   '' in settings.py.

In settings.py

```
SUMMERNOTE_THEME = 'bs4'  # Show summernote with Bootstrap4
```

Comment: [`bs4` uses Bootstrap 4.3.1](https://github.com/summernote/django-summernote/blob/8b17863d44ad1a588ea46d79203461275456e654/django_summernote/utils.py#L86-L88), is it possible to use bootstrap 4.5.0 instead?